# TextFormField with checkbox dynamic in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to make inputs with checkbox in flutter as seen in this image:
[image]

I have followed a tutorial to dynamically add the inputs and it works fine, but I also need a checkbox for canda input so that the user can mark more than one option.

[image]

This is the tutorial: https://blog.devgenius.io/add-remove-textformfields-dynamically-in-flutter-5bef6948e778

Any solution?

Comment: can you add your code snippet?

Comment: If You want this type of text form field you need to create your own custom text form field widget using Container and another widget. I think this is a single way to get these results.